# Why field `data` in `eth_call` optional?

Tags: json-rpc, eth-call

Based on https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call

The `data` is optional, but it also says it contains hash of the method signature.

In what scenario you can send a `eth_call` without `data` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation can be is a bit misleading here, I think because it aims to simplicity. The following statement from the current [RPC official documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call):

> `data`: `DATA` - (optional) Hash of the method signature and encoded parameters. For details see [Ethereum Contract ABI in the Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/abi-spec.html)

It should contains more details, maybe something like this:

> `data`: `DATA` - (optional) It contains arbitrary data. When calling a smart contract, `DATA` will be made available to it. Because Solidity is often used to develop and to compile smart contracts, `DATA` usually contains hash of the method signature and encoded parameters for the smart contract. See [Ethereum Contract ABI in the Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/abi-spec.html) for more details.

Under the hood, Solidity compiler transforms smart contract's functions into separate pieces of EVM instructions, and it also automatically inserts a selector - or switch statement - at the beginning of every compiled contract. The selector's duty is to redirect the execution flow to a specific piece of code based on parameters sent by caller through the `data` field.

Comment: Thanks. I found that too after took a close look at how a contract call executed on EVM.

Answer (score 2):

When `data` is empty (and there is no receive ether function) the fallback function will be called.

See: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/contracts.html#fallback-function

Prior to Solidity 0.4.0 this was used to send ETH to a contract.

Comment: Yeah, but what exactly is the point in doing an RPC on the fallback function? It doesn't return anything, so calling it NOT in a transaction seems pointless.